# 2 WPF and a DLL, model change notification

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to make two WPF projects and a DLL project in my solution following MVVM.

A first WPF to be used as a management panel for the second WPF (ex: you write text, press a button and the text is displayed in the second WPF Window).

I want to put my Models in the DLL.

My problem is that i don't know how to display the text (notify ?) in the second WPF.

I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the viewmodel.

And then I'm stuck, I don't know what to do...

My Solution looks like this :

WPF_Solution

1. DisplayWPF

   - MainWindow.xaml
2. Dll_mvvm

   - Text.cs :
3. ManagementWPF

   - DisplayViewModel.cs
   - MainWindow.xaml

Both Display and Management refer to the DLL.

Text.cs :

```cs
public class Text
{
    string _textToDisplay;

    /// <summary>
    /// Text to display on screen
    /// </summary>
    public string TextToDisplay
    {
        get { return _textToDisplay; }
        set { _textToDisplay = value; }
    }
}
```

DisplayViewModel.cs :

```cs
public class DisplayViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Text _text;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs the default instance of a ToDisplayViewModel
    /// </summary>
    public DisplayViewModel()
    {
        _text = new Text();

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Accessors
    /// </summary>
    public Text Text
    {
        get { return _text; }

        set { _text = value; }
    }



    public string TextToDisplay
    {
        get { return Text.TextToDisplay; }
        set
        {
            if (Text.TextToDisplay != value)
            {
                Text.TextToDisplay = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("TextToDisplay");
            }
        }
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        // take a copy to prevent thread issues
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Management Panel :

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private DisplayViewModel _displayThings;
    private Affichage.MainWindow _displayer = new Affichage.MainWindow();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _displayThings = (DisplayViewModel)base.DataContext;
        _displayer.Show();
    }

    private void disp_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _displayThings.TextToDisplay = textBox.Text;
    }
}
```

And the WPF are just a button and a textbox in the Control window, and a textbox in the Display window. Linked to the viewmodel

```xml
<Window.DataContext>
    <!-- Declaratively create an instance of DisplayViewModel -->
    <local:DisplayViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

The TextBox is binded with `Text="{Binding TextToDisplay}`"

Should my Viewmodel be share din the DLL too ?

How to notify the other project that ther was a change in the model ?

Comment: Please don't add stuff like CLOSED or SOLVED to your title.  What's changed?  Did you find a simple bug?  Or did the answer below help you fix your problem?  If the first, add an answer with some details and you can select it as correct.  If the second, select the answer below as correct.

Comment: I didn't really solve anything, I just reworked the whole code and it's almost what I tried to do. (sorry for "close" I didn't know what to do since I've reworked everything, I shuld have deleted the post instead)

Comment: You could, but with a new account, deleted questions can add up to an automatic ban.  Adding your own answer and selecting it as correct may seem weird, but that's how we normally do it around here.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following markup as it will create a new instance of the DisplayViewModel class:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <!-- Declaratively create an instance of DisplayViewModel -->
    <local:DisplayViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

...and assign the DataContext property of the child window to the instance of the DisplayViewModel class that you are actually setting the TextToDisplay property of:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private DisplayViewModel _displayThings = = new DisplayViewModel();
    private Affichage.MainWindow _displayer = new Affichage.MainWindow();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _displayer.DataContext = _displayThings;
        _displayer.Show();
    }

    private void disp_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _displayThings.TextToDisplay = textBox.Text;
    }
}
```